# How to use a constants value as a hash key

Tags: raku

Is there a simple way to use the value of a defined constant as a hash / pair key in Perl6?

For instance :

```
constant KEY = "a string";
my %h = ( KEY => "a value" );
```

This will creatre a key of "KEY" not "a string".

I can do :

```
my %h = ( "{KEY}" => "a value" );
```

But that seems a bit clunky. I was wondering if there was a better way?

Answer (score 16):

The most convenient options would be to either:

- Declare the constant with a sigil (such as `constant $KEY = "a string";`), thus avoiding the problem in the first place
- Wrap the left hand side in parentheses (like `(KEY) => "a value"`), so it won't be treated as a literal
- Write it instead as `pair(KEY, "a value")`

Also, note that:

```
my %h = ( "{KEY}" => "a value" );
```

Is a useless use of parentheses, and that:

```
my %h = KEY, "a value";
```

Will also work, since non-`Pair`s in the list of values to assign to the hash will be paired up. It loses the visual pairing, however, so one of the previously suggested options is perhaps better.